# How to implement Row-Level-Security (RLS) in a SQL-Server database 2015 using AD groups?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssis, ssms, row-level-security

I have a SQLServer database containing employees working in different provinces of the country.
I'm trying to automate a report in SSRS that will be sent to executives. This report should only display employees from a particular province based on an executive's AD group.

For example:
- Joe Blo is an executive in the province of Ontario and he's in the AD group ONT-Executives.
The extracted report should only display employees that have Ontario in the Province column in my database.
- Fox Brown is an executive in the province of Alberta and he's in the AD group ALB-Executives. The report should display only Alberta's employees.

I know this is possible using Row-Level-Security (RLS), but I feel like the online documentation for using AD groups is not very clear considering my efficiency with SQL.

I created a database schema called RLS. I'm unsure where to go from now so any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Row level security was added in SQL 2016.  You might want to read this similar question & answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56374061/how-can-i-achieve-row-level-security-in-sql-server-2014

Comment: Instead of RLS.. why not use a parameterised data driven subscription.. pass in the ONT as parameter and get only those employees and send the ONT executives the corresponding result?